# How to add the cvs head of a project as dependency?

Tags: git, maven, github, dependency-management, leiningen

I want to update a dependency of my project to its most recent state, (latest commit of its master branch), which is not released yet.

More specifically, the project I want to depend is using git and hosted public on GitHub. I use lein, which stands on the shoulders of maven.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dependency is declared as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, you can [change it to track the latest commit of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

Then any `git submodule update --remote` would update the dependency to the latest commit.
(Don't forget to add and commit in the parent repo the new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, the [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), which represents the new SHA1 of the submodule).